# How can I get the RMW working?

Tags: ros

I keep getting this message below when trying to install ros2 humble. I have ubuntu 22.04LTS.

```
[ERROR] [1689111314.030165235] [rcl]: Error getting RMW implementation identifier / RMW implementation not installed (expected identifier of 'rmw_connext_cpp'), with error message 'failed to load shared library 'librmw_connext_cpp.so' due to dlopen error: librmw_connext_cpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, at ./src/shared_library.c:99, at ./src/functions.cpp:65', exiting with 1., at ./src/rcl/rmw_implementation_identifier_check.c:139
```

I have also already installed RTIS Conntext.

Comment: Use the command `dpkg -S librmw_connext_cpp.so` to find the name(s) of the package(s) that provide `librmw_connext_cpp.so`. `sudo apt install ` one of these packages.